# How does a multiphase DC chopper circuit work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics

This is a buffer capacitor and multiphase chopping in Traction applications. 
The solid black rectangles are inductors, the right rectangle is the R-L load and the solid black triangles are representing the GTO's.

The circuit is supposed to be a multiphase chopper. 
I spent an awful amount of time to figure the working of this circuit out, but so far no results. 
[image]
I even tried to simulate the circuit, but couldn't make it work. Here is my simulation.

P.S I don't have any GTO in my simulation program, and I can't import them, so I used a Darlington of n-channel MOSFET and PNP BJT to mimic the IGBT, or any other gate turn of regulator switch.

[image]

Source: Electrical Machines and Drives by Jan Melkebeek.

Comment: @user287001 I provided the source together with all the description on this very subject.  My professor is the author, I asked him before, he said "Shut up and don't try to waist my time"

Comment: My comments are needless and somehow wrong guesses. I removed them and wrote an answer after you inserted the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inserted textbook snippet makes the story clear. The reduction of the peak current isn't the clou, the idea is to reduce the effect of very long supply line. The inductor Lk is like a transformer winding with center tap. Its idea is to make sure one thyristor gets closed when another is fired. The transformer provides a reverse voltage to the other end. The thyristors generally need RC snubber circuit to limit the anode-cathode voltage during turn-off. The reverse pulse makes less energy wasting snubbers effective enough and resetting the snubber for a new pulse takes less time. Lk limits the rise speed of the current and that is also a common demand of thyristors. Probably separate current rise brake choke is unnecessary as extra part.

By chopping the motor voltage at high enough frequency one can prevent pulsed voltage drops in the line. There's no need for LC lowpass filter, wire inductance Lk and inserted capacitor  Cb are enough. The extra circuits such as the snubber and Lk limit the max switching frequency, so high enough frequency with one thyristor maybe isn't possible, but having 2 of them the pulse frequency can be doubled.

The diagram is a skeleton. Triggering needs transformers to make different DC level possible and the thyristors must have snubbers. If you simply want to simulate the principle use controlled ideal switches instead of GTOs. Have L, Lb, freewheel diodes and Lk  to see their effects. Try at first without snubbers to see are they needed. The motor can be a DC battery + a resistor+ a big magnetizing inductor in series. The DC battery presents the voltage induced by the rotation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying there aren't other problems with your simulation but this one is glaring: -

[image]

The 1 H inductor is completely shorted out. Also try and learn how to cut and paste pictures.

Comment: You're right about the both problems. I'll try to fix them, but still I can't analysis the original circuit.

Comment: And to be hones I have no clue how an inductor can have three terminals

Comment: It's called a centre-tap